# Setting high frame rate recording in Swift

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, camera, slowmotion

i'm trying to create an app to record video at 120fps but i'm having troubles.

First, when `print(device.activeFormat)`, i get this in the logs

```
AVCaptureDeviceFormat: 0x13fe49890 'vide'/'420v' 1920x1080, { 2- 30 fps}, fov:58.080, supports vis, max zoom:104.38 (upscales @1.55), AF System:1, ISO:34.0-544.0, SS:0.000024-0.500000
```

but my device is an iPhone 5s which supports 120fps, don't know why the range here is 2-30fps.

Second, when i do `device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 120)` to change the max frame rate to 120 fps, i get this error in the logs:

```
[AVCaptureVideoDevice setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration:] - the passed activeVideoMaxFrameDuration 1:120 is not supported by the device.
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I just checked my phone, Settings->Photos & Camera->Camera, and there is no 120 fps for Record Video. 120 fps seems to appear only in the Record Slo-mo option. In your code, you are setting video fps. Since it fails, does that mean the phone actually doesn't support 120 fps on regular video recording?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from your print(device.activeFormat), the max support fps is 30 given {2- 30 fps}. Therefore, setting 120 fps with device.activeVideoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 120) is not supported.